# Mapping from different properties based on discriminator value using AutoMapper

Tags: .net, automapper

I have one very general object that I want to map to a destination type using AutomMapper, but I want to map it to different types depending on the value of a property in the source type. For example, let's say I have:

```
public class Source
{
    public string Discriminator { get; }
    public string ValueA { get; }
    public string ValueB { get; }
}

public class Target
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to map Source.ValueA to Target.Value if Source.Discriminator == "A" and Source.ValueB to Target.Value if Source.Discriminator == "B".

Is this possible using AutoMapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Mapper.Map<Spurce, Target>().ForMember(x => x.Value, x => x.MapFrom(y => {
    if(y.Discriminator == "A")
        return y.ValueA;
    return y.ValueB;
    });
```

Comment: I could, but I want to use Automapper's functionality if possible. I reality I have several source fields and several target fields. If I use the method you suggest I will have to add several if/else-statements for each target member which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Karl, You don't need to hard code it the way I did here. You might just as well use reflection based on your conventions.